# Codeigniter pagination not rendering pagination links

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Hello I have the following code,

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
$this->data['products'] = $this->products_model->get_products_and_category($this->uri->segment(4));

$config['base_url'] = base_url()."admin/products/manage/";
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('products')->num_rows();
$config['per_page'] = 20;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="btn-group">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
$config['anchor_class'] = 'class="btn" ';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<div class="btn">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</div>';
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;

$this->pagination->initialize($config); 
$this->data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

$this->template->build('admin/products/index', $this->data);
```

The query this is being run by `get_products_and_category($this->uri->segment(4))` looks like this,

```
public function get_products_and_category($offset=0) {
    $this->db->select('products.product_id, products.product_title, products.product_created, products.parent_category, categories.category_id, categories.category_title')
    ->from('products')
    ->join('categories' , 'products.parent_category = categories.category_id', 'left')
    ->order_by('products.product_title', 'ASC')
    ->limit(25, $offset);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

There are 25 results in my table, and I want to show 20 per page, so by my maths the pagination class should create 2 links (page 1 and page 2) the first page should 20 results on it, and the second should have 4 results,  however I am not getting any links at all, am I doing some wrong?

Comment: I assume you're echo'ing data['pagination'] in your template, right?

Comment: Absolutley - that would be really stupid of me

Comment: @sico87, people make stupid mistakes sometimes, its always worth asking, especially since we don't see your code for the view.

Comment: Can you show us admin/products/index?

Comment: Just to ask why you have different different url for the pagination $config['base_url'] =...admin/products/manage but you are loading different one $this->template->build('admin/products/index') in your template?

Answer (score 4):

The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement.

Now you have 25 results and you limit your query to return 25 results so your pagination might not work correctly.

Try passing the $config[per_page] in the query

```
$this->data['products'] = $this->products_model->get_products_and_category($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4));
```

And then in the query (notice we pass the per_page variable to the limit())

```
public function get_products_and_category($num, $offset=0) {
$this->db->select('products.product_id, products.product_title, products.product_created, products.parent_category, categories.category_id, categories.category_title')
->from('products')
->join('categories' , 'products.parent_category = categories.category_id', 'left')
->order_by('products.product_title', 'ASC')
->limit($num, $offset); // Here we pass the per_page var

$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I don,t believe that would affect the pagination creation. The pagination library is being passed the parameters that there are 25 rows in total and 20 items will be shown in one page.So it should have produced 2 anchors, regardless of the query result. The library does not have anything to do with the query result.

Answer (score 0):

Altrim answer is very good. But to stay conform to CodeIgniter, I recommend using this instead :

```
public function get_products_and_category($offset=0) {
    $this->db->select('products.product_id, products.product_title, products.product_created, products.parent_category, categories.category_id, categories.category_title')
    ->from('products')
    ->join('categories' , 'products.parent_category = categories.category_id', 'left')
    ->order_by('products.product_title', 'ASC')
    ->limit($this->per_page, $offset); // Here we pass the per_page var

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

You already define per_page in `$config['per_page'] = 20;`

Since `$this->pagination->initialize($config);` transform `$key (per_page) => $value (20)` in `$this->$key = $value` in `initialize` function.